# .NET Core WebApi Hosting Issue in IIS Express

Tags: c#, iis, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm trying to host .Net Core2 default WebApi project on my Local IIS Server in Windows 10.

I just published the default project to a local folder without making any change on it and hosted it on IIS.
But it gives me this error when I try to access the URI

[image]

My web.config file as follow:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
   <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\ToHost2.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" />
   </system.webServer>
</configuration>
<!--ProjectGuid: 3be731b8-79e8-4828-a016-54606c34c081-->
```

Please help me to track where I have made mistake.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you set the application pool as "no managed code"? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/?tabs=aspnetcore2x#install-web-deploy-when-publishing-with-visual-studio

Answer (score 1):

You need to install the [.NET Core Windows Server Hosting bundle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/?tabs=aspnetcore2x#install-the-net-core-windows-server-hosting-bundle)

Comment: @JayNaz it is not the runtime but another installer.

Comment: Have you followed all the steps in that article ? Probably you're missing something else.

Answer (score 0):

Convert the Web api project folder as application in IIS tool.

right click on api project folder and convert as application i think it will be work for you